# Finding differences in two text files from DriveApp

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I'm making a script that copies the contents of a Google Doc into a text file and stores it on Google Drive. The user then edits the document and when they are finished it copies a new version to drive in a separate file. I have this part done, but now I need to know how to make the script automagically compare the differences in the text and then change the color of these differences in the doc. Any ideas?

The only thing I've tried is asking my friend who knows a lot more than me when it comes to programming, haha. He couldn't help me.

```
function copyQuestions() {
  var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
  var getquestions = body.getText()
  DriveApp.createFile('tempquestions.txt', getquestions);
  DocumentApp.getUi()
  .alert('Questions have been copied to a new file on Google Drive. Get to work, and be sure not to delete the file!')
}
function copyAnswers() {
  var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
  var getanswers = body.getText()
  DriveApp.createFile('tempanswers', getanswers);
  DocumentApp.getUi()
  .alert('Coloring answers...')
}
```

The script creates files with copies of the document's contents. I need to know how to compare the differences between the two of those now. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need a Diff engine. You can attempt to write your own by leveraging well-known algorithms such as [Levenshtein Distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) or [Dice's Coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S%C3%B8rensen%E2%80%93Dice_coefficient) but if you're not so inclined you can try looking for an existing javascript library that's compatible with Apps Script.

Did a quick search and found a few open-source repos. I can't vouch for their compatibility with Apps Script, but at least one of them seems viable (JSDiff supports EcmaScript 3 where Apps Script supports up to EcmaScript 5):

---

### JSDIFF

- Source (web-packed) : http://incaseofstairs.com/jsdiff/diff.js
- Github : https://github.com/kpdecker/jsdiff

---

### NODE-DELTA

- Github : https://github.com/znerol/node-delta

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: If they do work with Apps Script, how would I set it up?

Comment: JSDiff has a web-packed source file (linked in answer) that you can try embedding in your app script as a script file. I can't guarantee that will work but its worth a shot. However if it does work, but sure to check the github link for instructions on how to use the library in your code.

Comment: I believe I know how to run regular JS in apps script, should I give that a try?

Comment: @Hampoon: It won't hurt to try.

Comment: Hey Dimu, have you ever used these? Do you know how I can configure it? I'm sorry, I'm new and really don't know what I'm doing. Haha.

Comment: Also, I have a tiny bit of experience with NodeJS by hosting Discord bots and I have my Raspberry Pi hosting a bot right now. Do you think if this doesn't work I could somehow get it working with that?

Comment: Busy with work, no time to test them out. You should be able to test JSDiff for yourself. Just [create a script file](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/projects#managing_files_in_a_project), copy & paste the diff.js file (linked above) into it, create another script file for your test code, and then read the github page (also linked above) for instructions on how to use the library. They have sample code there you can try but you'll have to modify them for use with Apps Script.

Comment: Hmm, okay. Thank you.

Comment: I figured out how to install a library or something which allowed me to compare text. So far I have it logging differences in two texts. We're getting there! :D